# Is there a similarity between the i 6/4 chord and the V chord in a minor key?

Tags: chords

In a lot of jazz standards there is a common alteration of the i chord which uses a descending bass note down to the 5th of the chord and then it resolves back to the i. To give an example in Dm, it would be

Dm > Dm/Bb > Dm/A > Dm

This movement to my ears sounds like a VI > V > i cadence. Is this because of the V > i movement in the bass?

Comment: @musicamante `Dm/A` is jazz "slash" chord notation, it means `Dm` chord with `A` in the bass, like `Dm: i6/4`

Comment: @MichaelCurtis sorry, for some reason I misread the chords thinking in C minor

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a similarity between the i 6/4 chord the V chord in a minor key?

Yes.

Using your example key `Dm: i6/4 V` both have the same bass tone: `A`. The view from the old figured bass point of view is the `i6/4` chord is just a double appoggiatura over the bass on the dominant, the fifth scale degree. In other words it views it not as a bona fide chord but a contrapuntal embellishment. It's similar to how a suspension doesn't change the harmonic analysis of a chord...

[image]

...the first one is the suspension where the second chord would normally be labeled just `V` with no regard to the suspension figure first creating a "chord" of `E A D` which is really just a contrapuntal embellishment of the real chord `E A C#`.

The second progress is labeled in a similar way. The second "chord" of `A D F` is considered a double appoggiatura embellishment of the real chord `A C# E`. So, `i6/4` isn't really a tonic chord, it is a dominant chord.

If you expand that as in a cadence...

[image]

...you could still take the view that the second "chord" of `A D F` is just a contrapuntal embellishment of a dominant chord.

> Dm > Dm/Bb > Dm/A > Dm...This movement to my ears sounds like a VI > V > i cadence. Is this because of the V > i movement in the bass?

[image]

They are similar in the bass tone being the same. Given the point about `i6/4` viewed as simply a type of dominant the bass becomes the strong harmonic factor. But I think many would consider the first example a kind of arpeggiating or walking bass, just outlining chord tones and fairly static. Certainly not equivalent to the second example with a proper dominant chord. I think it needs to be heard in context. If that `Dm` were placed in a larger sequence like `A7 Dm7 Gm7` the the feeling that the `Dm/A` is a dominant seem much reduced.

[image]

Comment: It's really interesting how things can be perceived completely differently depending on the context!

Comment: wow, this is more than I could have hoped for, very helpful indeed